# Running Python scripts on an Ubuntu machine disables the network port

Tags: python, ubuntu, networking

One of the Ubuntu machines I manage is having an issue where it completely disables the network port every time I run a Python script on it. It does not matter what the script is, after about 5 minutes of execution, the network show as unreachable. I have tried disabling and re-enabling the network via the terminal but this does not bring the port back online. Even doing a normal reboot does nothing, I have to physically unplug the machine to get it to come back up. Has anyone had this problem before?

Edit: Linux version 4.15.0-99-generic (gcc version 7.5.0). The network is a domain with this computer hooking up via a dynamic IP linked to a static IP router. This is only one of about 50 Linux machines we (college IT staff) manage and this is the only one that has ever done anything like this. Other computers in the same room with the exact same network setup run scripts perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/socket.html#example and read the part where it talks about why you need to use SO_REUSEADDR.